# The Ultimate Typo

Tags: word, cipher, no-computers

Here are four sentences that I made up. But I accidentally shuffled the characters in every column! Can you figure out what the original sentences were?

> ```
> Tossseplontretltcoanezpasntbteko
> Alwshonrdnfteseahedezauctydtxtoe
> Yhiyasueroreaaalneondoheanoomaao
> Aluonevtecceildaiypuywlaraourodk
> ```

Comment: Is it possible that the fourth and fifth letters on the third line have also accidentally been swapped?

Comment: Anything is possible... :)

Comment: Should that read "every row" instead of "every column"? Columns are up/down, rows are across

Comment: @CDspace nope, see the accepted answer. "Every row" would make it almost impossible to find the intended answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it should say something like this:

> `Youshouldnttellanyonewhatnottodo
>  Thissentenceisalieandaparadoxtoo
>  Alwyasproofreadthepuzzlesyoumake
>  Alsonevercreateacodeyoucantbreak`

(Obviously the lines can be permuted freely; I've opted to arrange them in rhyming couplets.)

The "ultimate typo" might be

> the transposition that remains in line three after fixing things as above.

Comment: Fun fact: by adding that last part to sentence 2, it's not actually a paradox anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Partial, I could get the first few words.

> This sentence is a